# hive query using regular expression

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

hi i was looking for a way to query a hive table ( user_acc_detl )
where a column (ACC_DETAILS) data looks like below,

```
COUNTRY[0]_united staes~DATE[0]_6/10/2014~AMOUNT[0]_200~ID[0]_20140509065052159324~COUNTRY[1]_united kingdom~DATE[1]_6/17/2014~AMOUNT[1]_125~ID[1]_20140516075156389761~COUNTRY[2]_Canada~DATE[2]_6/26/2014~AMOUNT[2]_200~ID[2]_20140515094013444121~COUNTRY[3]_Mexico~DATE[3]_7/3/2014~AMOUNT[3]_1200~ID[3]_20140601000937914898
```

i can query the hive table by

```
select ACC_DETAILS["COUNTRY[0]"] as COUNTRY, ACC_DETAILS["DATE[0]"] as DATE,  ACC_DETAILS["AMOUNT[0]"] as BILLAMOUNT, ACC_DETAILS["ID[0]"] as PAYMENTID
from user_acc_detl
```

the above query gives the data for country[0], date[0], amount[0], id[0] which is fine.

Question - all i need to query it using just country, date, amount....without specifying as country[0]...

Question - is there a regular expression way to modify the query accordingly. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this is to wrap your query in a view:

```
CREATE VIEW user_acc_detl_simple AS
SELECT ACC_DETAILS["COUNTRY[0]"] as COUNTRY
     , ACC_DETAILS["DATE[0]"] as DATE
     , ACC_DETAILS["AMOUNT[0]"] as BILLAMOUNT
     , ACC_DETAILS["ID[0]"] as PAYMENTID
FROM user_acc_detl;

SELECT country, date, billamount, paymentid FROM user_acc_detl_simple;
```